# Finding Max cell index and value from list object double type

Tags: c#, list, double, max, min

I have the following code which generates 4 lists in an object (each contains 24 cells):

```
    public class MyDataObject
    {
        public double AmountNeed { get; set; }
        public double TotalLose { get; set; }
        public double TotalGain { get; set; }
        public double TotalCost { get; set; }
    }

var L = new List<MyDataObject>();
for (int z=0; z < list_Exp.Count; z++)
    {

     var d = new MyDataObject();

     d.AmountNeed =Math.Ceiling((goalexp - currentexp) / (list_Exp[z]));
     d.TotalLose = d.AmountNeed * (list_Amount_MadeFrom_One[z] * list_BuyPrice_MadeFrom_One[z] + list_Amount_MadeFrom_Two[z] * list_BuyPrice_MadeFrom_Two[z]);
     d.TotalGain = d.AmountNeed * list_AmountMade[z] * list_SellPrice[z];
     d.TotalCost = d.TotalGain - d.TotalLose;
     L.Add(d);

   }

dataGrid.ItemsSource = L;
```

Each one of the lists is `double` type.

Once i have finished creating the lists, i want to find the max and min value of d.TotalCost.

The final goal is to find the `min` and `max` row index so i can color those lines in the datagrid.

Thank You.

Comment: Is this in WinForms?

Comment: Wpf if i understand you correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by LINQ.

First make your `MyDataObject` implement `IComparable<MyDataObject>`. Implement the `CompareTo` method like this:

```
public int CompareTo(MyDataObject other) {
    return this.TotalCost.CompareTo(other.TotalCost);
}
```

Then, you can just use this find out the index of the data object with the largest total cost:

```
L.IndexOf(L.Max())
```

An alternative way is to do this:

```
L.FindIndex(x => x.TotalCost == L.Max(y => y.TotalCost))
```

Comment: can you please explain me how to implement Icomparable in this example? i edited the question. Thank you mate. @sweeper

Comment: @ben edited. I don't quite like the icomparable approach though, I suggest you should use the latter approach.